# Dynamic service id in an argument in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, config

Is it possible to set the service id in an argument dynamically (e.g. like a class name which could be set via parameter) in Symfony 2 (xml configs)?

The following does not work

```
<service id="myservice" class="myservice.php">
    <argument type="service" id="%dynamic_service_name%" />
</service>

<service id="service1" class="foobar\service1" />
<service id="service2" class="foobar\service1" />
```

the idea is to set the param %dynamic_service_name% dynamically to "service1" or "service2", so the needed instance/object is passed to myservice-class, e.g. in the Extension::load() via $container->setParameter('dynamic_service_name','service1');

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please add the parameters to the code you've provided. There are no parameters in your code given.

Answer (score 16):

You can use CompilerPass:

```
class DynamicServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('myservice')
            ->setArguments(array(new Reference($container->getParameter('dynamic_service_name'))));
    }
}
```

and add it to your Bundle class:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $container->addCompilerPass(new DynamicServiceCompilerPass());
}
```

**FOLLOW UP**:

Since Symfony 2.4 you can use [Expression Language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) like this:

```
<services>
    <service id="myservice" class="My\Service">
        <argument type="expression">service(container.hasParameter('dynamic_service_name') ? parameter('dynamic_service_name') : 'default_service_name')</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read a parameter into your service definition, with the `parameter()` function, and create a service with the `service()` function. So you can create a dynamic service

In your parameters.yml

```
  parameters:
      dynamic_service_name:  mydynamicservice
```

In your services.yml

```
  myservice:
        class: My\Service
        arguments:['@=service(parameter("dynamic_service_name"))']
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the symfony2 docs ;)

```
<!-- app/config/config.xml -->
<parameters>
    <parameter key="my_mailer.class">Acme\HelloBundle\Mailer</parameter>
    <parameter key="my_mailer.transport">sendmail</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="my_mailer" class="%my_mailer.class%">
        <argument>%my_mailer.transport%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

Is this what you're after?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#service-parameters

Edit:

This is one of my services, using a parameter. However, it is in YAML. This works just fine. As you can see, it's using the class name with the namespace of the class in the parameter.

```
parameters:
    seer_ukd_wright_gallery.gallery_helper.class: SeerUK\DWright\GalleryBundle\DependencyInjection\GalleryHelper

services:
    seer_ukd_wright_gallery.gallery_helper:
        class: %seer_ukd_wright_gallery.gallery_helper.class%
        arguments:
            em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Comment: unfortunately not, because with this "solution" i just pass a string to the service and not an instance of an object/service..

Comment: If you're trying it with the php file names, that won't work... Make sure you're using the class name, with the namespace. Have another look through that documentation page. I'll give you an example from one of my services, it's in YAML though...

Comment: of course setting a class name dynamically via a parameter is possible but i want to set the id of an service dynamically

Comment: On that same page in the symfony 2 documentation, the one in my answer, take a look at the PHP tab, you'd probably be able to program that in there if you wanted.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `@%entity_manager_service_id%` in place of `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly how it can be done using the container itself as a factory. You can then define your 'dynamic_service_name' as either service1 or service2 and it'll load in that service. (XML for a factory is slightly different in 2.6 but should still work the same)

```
<service id="service1" class="foobar\service1" />
<service id="service2" class="foobar\service1" />

<service id="some.service" class="foobar\service1"
             factory-service="service_container"
             factory-method="get">
        <argument>%dynamic_service_name%</argument>
    </service>

<service id="myservice" class="myservice.php">
    <argument type="service" id="some.service" />
</service>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Peter Fox' answer, here's the equivalent in YAML:

```
some.service:
    class: Foobar\Service1
    factory_service: service_container
    factory_method: get
    arguments:
        - %dynamic_service_name%
myservice:
    class: MyService
    arguments:
        - @some.service
```

There are two small differences in how the classes of the two services are specified. I'm not familiar with the use of filenames as classes and `foobar\service1` is also not PSR-compliant, so I replaced these.