# symfony 2 loading sub service by config parameter

Tags: php, symfony, service

I am trying to load a service into another service, using a config param to state the vendor name.

```
 <service id="test" class="MyClass"> 
      <argument type="service" id="%my.vendor%"></argument>
 </service>
 <service id="vendor.mytest" class="MyServiceClass"></service>
```

At this point i have confirmed that the `%my.vendor%` parameter is the string `"vendor.mytest"`, but it is not seen that way, it is literally reading the string `%my.vendor%` as the `"id"` of the requested service.

Is there a way to do this, properly...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried  [Using the Expression Language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614929/dynamic-service-id-in-an-argument-in-symfony2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  [Expression Language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language) (Available from Symfony 2.4:):

```
      <service id="test" class="MyClass"> 
        <argument type="expression">service(parameter('my.vendor'))</argument>
    </service>
```

hope this help

Comment: sorry forgot to mark this as such, but this is the correct answer, thanks so much @Matteo !